# How to Call Method of ModelB.js from within ModelA.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop, loopbackjs

I am working with loopback 2.0.

I generated my models with the yeoman generator and added a js file for each model to extend its behavior.

***How can I call a method from ModelA within ModelB?***

**EXAMPLE**

**Folder structure:**

```
/common
  /models
    Car.json
    Car.js
    Engine.json
    Engine.js
...
```

**Car.js:**

```
module.exports = function(Car) {
  Car.drive = function(destination, fn) { ... }
  ...
};
```

**Engine.js:**

```
module.exports = function(Engine) {
  Engine.doSomething = function(something, fn) { 
    // *** Here is where I want to invoke a method from the Car.js
    var loopback = require('loopback');
    var Car = loopback.models.Car;
    Car.drive('49.1234,12.1234', fn);
    // ***
  }
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model class such as *Engine* will have a property *app* to provide access to other models, for example:

```
module.exports = function(Engine) {
  Engine.doSomething = function(something, fn) { 
    // *** Here is where I want to invoke a method from the Car.js
    var Car = Engine.app.models.Car;
    Car.drive('49.1234,12.1234', fn);
    // ***
  }
  ...
};
```